# PQN normalization for Metabolomic analysis

Tags: r, normalization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k27zO.png)

The above is the first 6 rows of my data. I want to normalize using the PQN method, and these are my R code getting from https://github.com/tidymass/masscleaner/blob/HEAD/R/normalize_data_pqn.R#L30:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- read.csv("mydata.csv", header=TRUE)

normalize_data_pqn <-
  function(x,
           pqn_reference = "median",
           pgn_reference_sample = NULL) {
    
    if (!is.null(pgn_reference_sample)) {
      if (pqn_reference == "mean") {
        mx <- as.numeric(apply(x[, pgn_reference_sample], 1 , mean))
      }
      if (pqn_reference == "median") {
        mx <- as.numeric(apply(x[, pgn_reference_sample], 1 , median))
      }
    } else {
      if (pqn_reference == "mean") {
        mx <- as.numeric(apply(x, 1 , mean))
      }
      if (pqn_reference == "median") {
        mx <- as.numeric(apply(x, 1 , median))
      }
    }
    
    # do the actual normalization
    new_x <-
      purrr::map(
        x,
        .f = function(value) {
          as.numeric(value / median(as.numeric(value / mx)))
        }
      ) %>%
      dplyr::bind_cols()
    
    rownames(new_x) <- rownames(x)
    return(new_x)
  }

normalize_data_pqn(x, pqn_reference = "median", pgn_reference_sample = NULL)
```

I got a warning message, and all values changed to NA.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50fjz.png)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on numerical variables of a dataframe?
Try in a random dataset:

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=20, min=1, max=50), nrow=5))
df <- cbind(label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), x)
str(df)

normalize_data_pqn <- function(x, pqn_reference = "median", pgn_reference_sample = NULL) {
  
  if (!is.null(pgn_reference_sample)) {
    if (pqn_reference == "mean") {
      mx <- as.numeric(apply(x[, pgn_reference_sample], 1 , mean))
    }
    if (pqn_reference == "median") {
      mx <- as.numeric(apply(x[, pgn_reference_sample], 1 , median))
    }
  } else {
    if (pqn_reference == "mean") {
      mx <- as.numeric(apply(x, 1 , mean))
    }
    if (pqn_reference == "median") {
      mx <- as.numeric(apply(x, 1 , median))
    }
  }
  
  # do the actual normalisation
  new_x <-
    purrr::map(
      x,
      .f = function(value) {
        as.numeric(value / median(as.numeric(value / mx)))
      }
    ) %>%
    dplyr::bind_cols()
  
  rownames(new_x) <- rownames(x)
  return(new_x)
}

df_norm <- cbind(label = df[ , 1], # merge label/group with numerical
                 normalize_data_pqn(df[ , -1], # except characters/factors
                                    pqn_reference = "median",
                                    pgn_reference_sample = NULL))
```